# How a function can process all mysql fetchAll result before returning?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

i want to select each word from my mysql instead of all

```php
function getItem($id)
{
    global $database;
    $stmt = $database->runQueryPlayer("SELECT vault FROM items WHERE index=?");
    $stmt->bindParam(1, $id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $stmt->execute();
    $result = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN);

    if ($result)
        return get_item_name_locale_name($result[0]); // Each number will result a name
    else {
        return '---';
    }
}
```

```
function get_item_name_locale_name($id)
{
    global $database;
    
    $stmt = $database->runQueryPlayer('SELECT name
        FROM itemlist
        WHERE index = ?');
    $stmt->bindParam(1, $id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $stmt->execute();
    $result = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN);
    
    if($result)
        return utf8_encode($result['name']);
    else return '';
}
```

also im using that on my player.php
**`<?php print getItem($row['index']); ?>`**

must return all of them but separate.

my column looks like that, each number is item
`78 26 50 28 -1 30 32 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0`,
because im using **function get_item_name_locale_name**, i should get

```
78 = name1
25 = name2
50 = name3
```

etc. but i get only first one.
and i need to ignore **-1 & 0**
thank you

even if i using this query, result is the same, just first word

```
    SELECT hunter.a_index, hunter.a_name,f.a_wearing
FROM itemnames hunter
INNER JOIN vault f ON hunter.a_index = f.a_wearing
GROUP BY hunter.a_index
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with Metin2CMS. But if the database layer is extending PDO, then the [fetchAll](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php) call here should return an array of values.

Your issue is you're only returning the processed first result:

```php
return get_item_name_locale_name($result[0]);
```

Instead, you should return an array of values all processed. You may use [array_map](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) for the purpose.

For PHP versions before 7.4:

```php
function getItem($id)
{
    global $database;
    $stmt = $database->runQueryPlayer("SELECT vault FROM items WHERE index=?");
    $stmt->bindParam(1, $id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $stmt->execute();
    $result = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN);

    if ($result) {
        // This is changed.
        return array_map(function ($row) {
            get_item_name_locale_name($row);
        }, $result);
    } else {
        return '---';
    }
}
```

For PHP 7.4+, you can use [arrow function](https://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.arrow.php) to shorten your code:

```php
function getItem($id)
{
    global $database;
    $stmt = $database->runQueryPlayer("SELECT vault FROM items WHERE index=?");
    $stmt->bindParam(1, $id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $stmt->execute();
    $result = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN);

    if ($result) {
        // This is changed.
        return array_map(fn($row) => get_item_name_locale_name($row), $result);
    } else {
        return '---';
    }
}
```

Comment: Notice: Array to string conversion in vault.php on line 57
Array after used first code

Comment: Can you please add `var_dump($row); exit();` before `get_item_name_locale_name($row);` and give me the output?

Comment: string(72) " 190 186 462 187 -1 188 189 166 166 170 871 -1 0 0 15 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 50 0"

Comment: Can you place a `var_dump($result); exit();` before the `if ($result) {` line, please?

Comment: what i get is - array(0) { }

Comment: It is impossible for an empry `$result` array to give anything like  `string(72) "190 ...`. There must be some misunderstanding. Can you show more of your code.

Comment: added on first question .

Comment: If I understand correctly, you're putting many numbers in your database table in the column `vault` of every single record. Right? Why don't you have multiple rows for each values? You can have a different table to store your `vault` values.

Comment: i cannot do that, my game is made like that , every character have have vault column, where items are stored. VAULT [ -1 -1 528 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 0 0 15 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0] translate will be VAULT [ -1 -1 Sword -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 0 0 Stone 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0] (0 and -1 means empty and SPACE is separator) if im using `var_dump(explode(" ", $result[0]));`  im getting the right return `--- array(5) { [0]=> string(0) "" 
[1]=> string(2) "78" 
[2]=> string(2) "26" 
[3]=> string(2) "50" 
[4]=> string(2) "28" 
[5]=> string(2) "-1" 
 }`